# inheritance from two parent classes

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I read about this ages ago but never tried it now I can't remember if this is possible or not. Is it possible to extend a class from two parents on php5 e.g.

class_d extends class_c and class_b

moreover can you do this if class_c and class_b are themselves extended from class_a ... so you get something like this

```
                          class_a
                  class_b          class_c
                          class_d
```

Comment: Retagged with multiple-inheritance, because that's the proper technical term for this type of inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

multiple inheritance (what you are looking for) is not supported in PHP.

You may want to check out [composition](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Object-Interaction-in-PHP-Introduction-to-Composition/) (where one class contains an instance of the parent) or even [interfaces](http://us.php.net/interfaces) if it applies specifically to your situation.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is called multiple inheritance. It doesn't exist in PHP.

Alternatives exist though: [Composition](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Object-Interaction-in-PHP-Introduction-to-Composition/), A parent could inherit the other, [mixins](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/125282) and maybe more...

From: http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10351110